# debezium date/time field value out of range: 0000-12-30T00:00:00Z

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

We use debezium to sync data to
In the source table we have column timestamptz `start_at`, when the value is zero `start_at='0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000 +00:00'`, but when we check the data in kafka, it's changed to `start_at = '0000-12-30T00:00:00Z'`. It lead to the error when we use jdbc sink connector to write to another postgres db
`ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "0000-12-30T00:00:00Z"`
here my debezium config about time.precesision.mode

```
    "time.precision.mode": "connect",
    "decimal.handling.mode": "double",
```

is there any solution to set data on kafka match zero timestamp value in postgres?

Comment: Year 0 does not exists, it's the year 1 BC or 1 AD and both are over 2000 years ago. I'm pretty sure Kafka didn't exist in those days...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the root cause of your situation is the timezone converter. When you apply the timezone in timestamp columns, Debezium converts to another timezone, which leads to the above error.

In a simple way, you may initial your timestamp value at another time instead (Example: 03-01-0001, 01-03-0001, ...)

Hoping this can help you

Comment: yeah, in our application, we set default value to 0 which does not make sense for a timestamp data type.
The fix is to set default value to another valid value like you said